# Solve "integer division in floating-point context" warning

Tags: java, intellij-idea, floating-point, suppress-warnings, integer-division

How does one solve the "integer division in floating-point context" warning, in this line of code:

```
int fps = 60;
double timePerTick = 1000000000 / fps;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When dividing two `int`s, you'll be using integer division, and only then promoting the result to a double, losing all the precision after the decimal point. You can use floating point precision by using a `double` literal instead:

```
double timePerTick = 1000000000.0 / fps;
// Here -----------------------^
```